# about postfix operator and sequence point

Tags: c, syntax

```
void func(int a){
printf("%d",a);
}

int main(){
  int a= 0;
  printf("%d", a);
  func(a++);
}
```

This is my code
BUT I can't understand why the result is 0
I think the result has to be 1

Because :

The side effect of updating the stored value of the operand shall occur between the previous and the next sequence point.

"a has to be increased before next sequence point"

All side effects of argument expression evaluations are sequenced before the function is entered

"There's sequence point before function is called"

So Isn't the variable a to be increased before func is called?

Can you tell me what am I understanding wrong?

THANK YOU

Comment: For comparison, `int b = a++;` would also initialize `b` to the old value of `a` even though the side-effect of storing `b` is sequenced after the value of `a++` is determined.

Answer (score 2):

`func(a++)` does not pass `a` to the function. It passes the value of the expression `a++`. The value of that expression is defined to be the value of `a` before the increment occurs.

It is entirely irrelevant when the increment occurs. The value of `a++` is the value of `a` prior to the increment.

Answer (score 1):

The postfix `++` operator evaluates to the **current** value of its operand, with the increment being a side effect.

So since `a` is 0 to start, that's the value that is passed to the function.

Comment: So the actual value of a before function is called is 1 right?

Comment: @도라에몽1 Yes, the value of `a` will be 1 before the function is called, but that will not be the value passed to the function.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting [sequencing rules](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order) (**emphasis mine**)

> 2. When calling a function (whether or not the function is inline and
>    whether or not function call syntax was used), there is a sequence
>    point **after the evaluation of all function arguments** (if any) which
>    takes place before execution of any expressions or statements in the
>    function body.

So, there's a sequence point *after* the evaluation of the function arguments. Now, this read with

> 1. Between the previous and next sequence point a scalar object must
>    have its stored value modified at most once by the evaluation of an
>    expression, otherwise the behavior is undefined.

will explain what is happening. The evaluation of the argument will happen and *then* there's a sequence point. The previous sequence point was the previous statement. So, evaluation of `a++` will yield `0` since it's the ***post***fix operator. This is what is passed to the function and hence the value `0`.

Here's confirming what's happening [via assembly](https://godbolt.org/z/xGazEbo7x) for the code

```
void foo(int a) {}

int main()
{
    int a = 0;
    foo(a++);
    return 0;
}
```

which yields the assembly:

```
foo:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], edi
        nop
        pop     rbp
        ret
main:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        sub     rsp, 16
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], 0
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-4]
        lea     edx, [rax+1]
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], edx
        mov     edi, eax
        call    foo
```

0 is moved at the memory location with the value of `rbp-4`. Then that value is moved to the register `eax`.  `mov edi, eax` moves this value to the `edi` register which is actually used by the `foo` function, called via `call foo`.

```
lea     edx, [rax+1]
mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], edx
```

These 2 instructions increment and store the value of `a`.

Comment: @도라에몽1 Added some assembly to _prove_ what we are all claiming.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int a; /* global */

void func(int arg) {
    printf("func: arg=%d, (global) a=%d\n", arg, a);
}

int main(void){
    a = 0;
    printf("main: (global) a=%d\n", a);
    func(a++);
    printf("main: (global) a=%d\n", a);
}
```

That program uses a global variable `a`. In `main`, the expression statement `func(a++);` is evaluated in the following order:

1. The arguments of `func` are evaluated in no particular order:

   1. For `func`'s `arg` parameter, the argument expression `a++` is evaluated yielding the old value of `a` (the value 0) with the side effect of `a` being incremented before the next sequence point.
2. Any remaining side effects of argument evaluation are completed (so `a` will be incremented to 1). (This is the sequence point after the evaluation of the function designator and function arguments but before the actual call.)
3. `func` is actually called.

(I have omitted some details, such as evaluation of the function designator `func`.)

The result of the above is that the old value of `a` (value 0) is passed to the `arg` parameter of `func`, but `a` will have been incremented (to value 1) when the body of function `func` is executed.

The above behavior can be seen in the program's output:

```
main: (global) a=0
func: arg=0, (global) a=1
main: (global) a=1
```